# Definition of Kervaire-Milnor group of homotopy sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Kervaire-Milnor famous paper as I know is the only source of definition (beside Antoni A. Kosinski that has no more information that Kervaire-Milnor paper) of $\Theta_n$ the group of $h$-cobordism classes of homotopy $n$-sphere. After defining connected sum, then proving that it is well-defined, associative, commutative, sphere as the identity element of connected sum operation. And if $M,M_1,M_2$ are closed simply connected and $M_1$ is $h$-cobordant to $M_2$ then $M_1\#M$ is $h$-cobordant to $M_2\#M$.

But I don't know what are the elements of  $\Theta_n$ the group of $h$-cobordism classes of homotopy $n$-sphere. they are manifolds that are homotopic to sphere? so what is the role of $h$-cobordism here?

My second question is: What does it means that "*$M$ bounds a contractible manifold $N$*"? its means is $M$ is a boundary of contractible manifold  $N$? i.e. it is null $h$-cobordant?

Comment: H-cobordism is an equivalence relation that respects connect sum, so h-cobordism classes of homotopy n-spheres is literally the monoid of homotopy n-spheres modulo the equivalence relation of being h-cobordant. For your second question, the answer is yes M bounds a contractible manifold, if it is the boundary of a contractible manifold.

Comment: It is monoid and is not a group? I thought it form a group. Anyway, Being group or not is a useful feature for connected sum?

Comment: $\Theta_n$ is indeed a group (this is in the Kervaire-Milnor paper). In general, the connected sum operation doesn't form a group operation--counterexamples abound, but a quick place to see this is in 2-manifolds.

Comment: @kamills: I know it about connected sum but not about $\Theta_n$. Is that proof there?

Comment: Yes. The content is Theorem 1.1, and the proof is at the end of section 2. The point is that connect sum operation certainly makes $\Theta_n$ into an abelian monoid with identity element the class of $S^n$, and for a homotopy $n$-sphere $M$ the manifold $-M$ (i.e., $M$ with reversed orientation) gives an inverse under $\#$ (precisely, $M \# -M$ is h-cobordant to $S^n$; this is Lemma 2.4).

Comment: @kamills: That's interesting that how a monoid become a group. This is true just for spheres? What abbot other manifolds?